# How can I show all "article" which have more than 3 "bids"?

Tags: sql, join, group-by, oracle-sqldeveloper, where-clause

I wanna show the "ArticleName" of all "offers" that have more than 3 "bids". The number of the "Bids" should be output.

I don't know how I can write it down. But I think I know the Logic. It should count the same number of the Table "bid" and the column "OID" and in the end it should paste the number which is more than 3.

Picture:
[image: More information about the structure of the tables "offer" and "bid". Also a "Expected result" which is shown the result. <-- really Important]

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT o.ArticleName, count(b.BID) as numberOfBids
    FROM Offer as o INNER JOIN bid as b ON o.oid = b.oid
    GROUP BY o.ArticleName
) as c
WHERE c.numberOfBids > 3
```

Answer (score 0):

Well that's easy enough:

```
Select ArticleName
     , count(*) NumberOfBids
  from Offer o
  join Bid b
    on b.oid = o.oid
 group by ARticleName
having count(*) >= 3
```